# Can you decompile from code that was written in assembly?

Tags: compilers, assembly

I've been reading a little about decompilers, and I think I get the general idea. I understand that I could start with either assembly or machine code, and then I'd have a decompiler which would target a specific high level language. In general high level code is far from being one-to-one with compiled output in assembly or binary, and so there are many different possible decompilations from a given  assembly or binary input.

As as sort of heuristic for how compilers work, I'm thinking about high-level control structures such as if, while and for. I know that there are probably many other types of considerations that have to be worked out when compiling code, but I've been thinking only about this part so far because I have some rough understanding about how it works. Then I understand that these structures are reduced down to jump and branch type instructions in assembly, and looking for certain patterns in jump and branch instructions in assembly code could indicate the use of if, while or for in a decompiled output.

Then if a certain program was written in assembly, would it be possible to decompile this to a higher level language, even though it wasn't compiled in the first place?
To my current naive understanding, I could imagine that maybe there are certain jump and branch instructions that produce desired program flow in assembly, but don't come from compiled if for or while. Maybe it's true that all possible branch and jump statements can be written in terms of if while and for, but I think this would have to be proven - at least it's not obvious to me why this would be true a priori.

If it's helpful to use an example high-level language in explaining this, then C without using goto is what I have in mind at the moment while thinking about the problem. I'm also interested in other aspects of decompilation apart from control structures, I just haven't considered them this far.

Comment: "Maybe it's true that all possible branch and jump statements can be written in terms of if while and for, but I think this would have to be proven - at least it's not obvious to me why this would be true a priori." – Proving that the so-called `WHILE` language, which only has `WHILE`, a single integer variable `X`, the two assignments `X := X + c` and `X := X - c`, `P; P`, and `WHILE X != 0 DO P END` is Turing-complete is a fairly standard homework exercise. Similarly, proving that the `GOTO` language is Turing-complete, which then in turn means that every `GOTO` program can be expressed as …

Comment: … a `WHILE` program and vice versa. OTOH, a "classic" `FOREACH` is not Turing-complete, it can only compute primitive-recursive functions. However, a C-style `for` is really just a `while` in disguise, and thus Turing-complete.

Comment: Yes, you can. Not all branch and jump instructions can be written as if/while/for.